# Easy communication of image between siblings

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to ReactJS and I would like to communicate between my components. 
When I click an image in my "ChildA" I want to update the correct item image in my "ChildB" (type attribute in ChildA can only be "itemone", "itemtwo", "itemthree"
Here is what it looks like

Parent.js

```
export default class Parent extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="mainapp" id="app">
                    <ChildA/>
                    <ChildB/>
            </div>

        );
    }
}

if (document.getElementById('page')) {
    ReactDOM.render(<Builder />, document.getElementById('page'));
}
```

ChildA.js

```
render() {
    return _.map(this.state.eq, ecu => {
        return (

             <img src="../images/misc/ec.png" type={ecu.type_eq} onClick={() => this.changeImage(ecu.img)}/>
        );
    });
}
```

ChildB.js

```
export default class CharacterForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            items: [
                { name: "itemone" image: "defaultone.png"},
                { name: "itemtwo" image: "defaulttwo.png"},
                { name: "itemthree" image: "defaultthree.png"},
            ]
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
        <div className="items-column">
          {this.state.items.map(item => (<FrameCharacter key={item.name} item={item} />))}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I can retrieve the image on my onClick handler in my ChildA but I don't know how to give it to my ChildB. Any hints are welcomed, thanks you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is for Parent to pass an event handler down to ChildA which ChildA will call when one of the images is clicked. The event handler will call `setState` in Parent to update its state with the given value, and then Parent will pass the value down to ChildB in its `render` method.

You can see this working in the below example. Since I don't have any actual images to work with—and to keep it simple—I've used `<button>`s instead, but the principle is the same.

```js
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      clickedItem: 'none',
    };
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ChildA onClick={this.handleChildClick}/>
        <ChildB clickedItem={this.state.clickedItem}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
  
  
  handleChildClick = clickedItem => {
    this.setState({ clickedItem });
  }
}

const items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

const ChildA = ({ onClick }) => (
  <div>
    {items.map(name => (
      <button key={name} type="button" onClick={() => onClick(name)}>
        {name}
      </button>
    ))}
  </div>
);

const ChildB = ({clickedItem}) => (
  <p>Clicked item: {clickedItem}</p>
);

ReactDOM.render(<Parent/>, document.querySelector('div'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this complete answer. I have some additional questions : every time you want to run an update of a component you must go through it's parent right?
What about if I have a bunch of information onClick, should I make a state each time, or maybe I can go with a list?

Comment: @FlickaMin "Every time you want to run an update of a component you must go through it's parent right." A component gets updated whenever its state changes *or* it receives new props from its parent. I'm not sure I understand the rest of your question. You can set as many properties as you want each time you call `setState`, and if you want to set multiple properties at once you should do it with one `setState` call (`this.setState({ foo: 1, bar: 2, ... })`) rather than calling `setState` multiple times in a row.

Comment: That was answers I was looking for, thanks for helping!